# Count array key data inside another array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the count of key data and sum them up and show. I need to count all the key data in a php array and show the output as below i tried but was not able to get all the array count.

```html
Output:
 chromi: 7
 detruch: 6
 detroy: 4
```

Find the array picture below, this is how i am getting array data
[image]

Comment: you want to count  how many element in the array ?

Comment: s i need to sum them up and show, above i hv given output

Comment: Don't post images of text. Use json or var_export instead

Comment: sure here after ill try to follow that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop the array, pick the first value using `reset()`, and count that index of the `$result` array.

```
$array = [
        ['someKey' => 'Value 1'],
        ['someKey1' => 'Value 1'],
        ['someKey2' => 'Value 2'],
        ['someKey3' => 'Value 3'],
    ];

$result = [];

foreach ($array as $v) {
    $value = reset($v);
    if (!isset($result[$value]))
        $result[$value] = 0;

    $result[$value] += 1;
}
print_r($result);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/Qlvti

Answer (score 2):

Better way will be to get array of values and use **[array-count-values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)**:

```
$array = [
        ['someKey' => 'Value 1'],
        ['someKey1' => 'Value 1'],
        ['someKey2' => 'Value 2'],
        ['someKey3' => 'Value 3'],
    ];

$arr = array_map(function ($e) {return reset($e);},$array);
print_r(array_count_values($arr));
```

Output will be:

```
Array
(
    [Value 1] => 2
    [Value 2] => 1
    [Value 3] => 1
)
```

I just improve @Qirel answer. This version can support multi-value to count. Live demo: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/3umOH)

Comment: Hi thanks it works but could u explain me how it works.

Comment: Sure - first I took the actual value you want to count (using the `array_map`) - in  your case `chromi`. Afterward I use build-in PHP function to count them

Answer (score 0):

First flip thekey with value and then loop the array to incrment the counters :

Try this snippet :

```
$chromi = 0 ;
$detruch = 0 ;
$detroy = 0;
$data = array_flip($data);
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
      if($key=='chromi'){
        $chromi++;
      }
      else if ($key=='chromi'){
      $chromi++
       }
        else if ($key=='detroy'){
      $detroy++
       }
}
```

Comment: actually the key also comes dynamically from DB, so we cant do like the above, Each user has his own type of editing option (i mean the key values), So for some user it may be different and goes n number